# Print array in a helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, printing

I am quite new in Ruby-on-rails. And I have a very simple question:
This one works in my view file:

```
- @posts.each do |child|
    = child.name
end
```

However, I can't create a helper method which takes an array as argument and iterate it with 'each'.

In my view file:

```
=f1(@posts)
```

In my helper file:

```
def f1(abc)
    abc.each do |child|
            puts child.name
    end
end
```

Please help me out with this silly problem. 
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
def f1(abc)
  output = ''
  abc.each do |child|
    output << "<br/> #{child.name}"
  end
  output
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In a running rails app `puts` outputs into the log file.

I recommend trying this approach:

Create a '_post' partial in the posts view directory, then put what you want to render out using `post` as the object (ie: `post.name`) then use `render @posts` in the view. This will automagically render the partial for each object in the collection.

See section 3.4.5 in the [Ruby on Rails Layouts and Rendering Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more info